# JPATH_COMPONENT contains administrator

Tags: component, joomla-3.4

Why does `JPATH_COMPONENT` contain administrator in the administrator controller of my component? (situated in administrator/components/com_mycomponent/controller.php)

It doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The `JPATH_COMPONENT` constant returns the path of the component **currently being executed**. Therefore if you call this constant from the admin part of your component, it will return the path with `administrator` in the name.

Have a look at the Joomla Constants Documentation for more detail:

https://docs.joomla.org/Constants

Hope this helps

#### Update:

`JPATH_COMPONENT` is the generic constant for the component being executed, however please bare in mind that there are also the following:

- `JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE`
- `JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR`

These come in handy if you want to call something from your backend component in the frontend and vise versa.

For example, lets say you had a form in the frontend, and once submitted, you needed to call a helper file locations in the admin component directory, you would use `JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR`

Comment: Then I don't see the point of `JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR`. Their documentation doesn't explicitly say that `/administrator/` might be part of it, like with: `JPATH_BASE`. But thanks. I'll have to work around it

Comment: @AnriëtteMyburgh - I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't see `JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE`